# Is it bad to pass more arguments than the function declares?

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```
function callback(obj){...}
```

Is it okay to pass in more objects than were declared in the function signature? *e.g.* call it like this:

```
callback(theObject, extraParam);
```

I tried it out on Firefox and it didn't seem to have a problem, but is it bad to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

JavaScript allows this, you can pass any arbitrary number of arguments to a function.

They are accessible in the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Arguments) object which is an array-like object that has numeric properties containing the values of the arguments that were used when the function was invoked, a `length` property that tells you how many arguments have been used on the invocation also, and a `callee` property which is a reference to the function itself, for example you could write:

```
function sum(/*arg1, arg2, ... , argN  */) { // no arguments defined
  var i, result = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
  return result;
}
sum(1, 2, 3, 4); // 10
```

The `arguments` object may look like an array, but it is a plain object, that inherits from `Object.prototype`, but if you want to use Array methods on it, you can invoke them directly from the `Array.prototype`, for example, a common pattern to get a *real array* is to use the Array `slice` method:

```
function test () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return args.join(" ");
}
test("hello", "world"); // "hello world"
```

Also, you can know how many arguments a function *expects*, using the `length` property of the function object:

```
function test (one, two, three) {
  // ...
}
test.length; // 3
```

Comment: can you call `test.length` within the function to test how many arguments the user inputs?

Comment: or could use `[].slice.call(arguments);`

Answer (score -3):

Yes do it - its good practice and is a powerful JavaScript feature

Comment: I think it is debatable that this is good practise. I don't consider it good practise, it's not obvious from the function signature whether the function is intended to take extra arguments or not.