# Why passing extra arguments to a function works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say I've defined a function :

```
function myAwesomeFunction(x){
    console.log(x);
}
```

now, what I expect is, if I'll call it like this: `myAwesomeFunction(1)` or `myAwesomeFunction('lol')` or `myAwesomeFunction('whatever')`, it'll work and it does.

but how does it work, even when I pass extra arguments to the function and simply ignores all arguments except the first one :

```
myAwesomeFunction('why so', 'serious?')
```

we don't even have any optional arguments in the above function?(i.e, like `(x, y='')`)

```js
function myAwesomeFunction(x){
    console.log(x);
}

myAwesomeFunction(1);
myAwesomeFunction('lol');
myAwesomeFunction('whatever');
myAwesomeFunction('why so', 'serious?')
myAwesomeFunction('why', 'so', 'serious?')
```

Comment: Because that's how the language has been designed. That's like asking why a variables is declared by writing `var x;` and not `variable x;`.

Comment: Also you *do* have access to them, via `arguments`.

Comment: Read this answer by @Prinzhorn  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694031/what-happens-if-i-call-a-js-method-with-more-parameters-than-it-is-defined-to-ac

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: was looking for an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694124/6518605) not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083910/why-passing-extra-arguments-to-a-function-works-in-javascript/47084109#comment81117067_47083910) @IngoBürk

Comment: @guest271314 was just trying to know, what I didn't know.

Answer (score 6):

You can call a Javascript function with any number of parameters, regardless of the function's definition.

Any named parameters that weren't passed will be undefined.

Javascript treats your parameters as an array. More specifically it's the `arguments` array, Named parameters in function declarations are just pointers to members of `arguments`. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 0):

When you defined the function, you gave it one parameter `x`

The language is designed to look for a single argument for each parameter, and ignore the others.

However, you are able to access the other arguments via the special `arguments` object.

Try typing `console.log(arguments)` within your function body and seeing what happens...