# JS: Higher Order Function Problem; Accept Array and Callback Function --> don't understand

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback

I have the following problem below:

My For Each

Write a function myForEach that accepts an array and a callback function. The behavior of myForEach should mirror the functionality of the native .forEach() array method as closely as possible.

Below is the code:

```
let sum = 0;

function addToSum(num) {
    sum += num;
}

let nums = [10, 20, 30];


function myForEach(anArray, callback){


  for (let i=0; i<anArray.length; i++){
    let num = anArray[i]; 
    //console.log(num)

    // I don't understand what this line of code is doing...
    callback(num, i, anArray); 
  }
  return undefined
}



myForEach(nums, addToSum);

console.log(sum); // 6
```

The above code works in this higher order function problem but I don't understand why.  Specifically, what is the following line of code mean:

```
 callback(num, i, anArray);
```

why are there 3 arguments?  and where are these arguments getting passed to?

Comment: `callback` is a reference to `addToSum`, which only uses the first argument `num` and ignores the next two passed.

Comment: It's just to exactly mirror the native `forEach` method. The callback to that takes 3 arguments, the same as here: the element, its index, and the array itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: By the way, not sure if this is "cheating", but wouldn't it be much easier to just use `function myForEach (anArray, callback, thisArg) { anArray.forEach(callback, thisArg); }`?

Answer (score 1):

"as closely as possible" is quite a harsh requirement. Javascript built-in functions are very complicated! These are the steps that the standard requires you to implement:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach

In layman's terms, since JS is a highly dynamic language, when you design a built-in function, you cannot just rely on parameters being what you expect them to be. In case of `forEach`:

- the argument can be not an array, and even not an object
- it might not have `length` or its `length` might be not a number
- the callback might be missing or be not a function

and so on. That's why an "as close as possible" implementation should do lots of safety checks before it actually starts looping and calling.

You can find an example of a real-world `forEach` polyfill on the MDN page (only look if you decided to give up on this):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694124/3729184) about it. Javascript doesn't care how many parameters you pass. For example, the following code still works but alerts `undefined` in the `addToSum` function:

```js
let sum = 0;

function addToSum(num, i, k, j) {
  sum += num;
  console.log("i is:" + i);
  console.log("k is:" + k);
  console.log("j is:" + j);
}

let nums = [10, 20, 30];

function myForEach(anArray, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    let num = anArray[i];
    //console.log(num)

    // I don't understand what this line of code is doing...
    callback(num);
  }
  return undefined
}

myForEach(nums, addToSum);
console.log(sum);
```

So the thing that happens in your original code is that `i` and `anArray` that you pass does not effect the `addToSum` function at all, and the only parameter this function need is `num` so everything works good.

Answer (score 0):

It's a callback function:

```
callback();
```

This is the function you passed into `myForEach` - in your code, it's `addToSum`, but it's a reference with a different name. It's used in case you have different functions for handling different things. In your code you can just as easily use `addToSum` and forget about `callback` altogether:

```js
let sum = 0;

function addToSum(num) {
  sum += num;
}

let nums = [10, 20, 30];


function myForEach(anArray) {


  for (let i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    let num = anArray[i];
    //console.log(num)

    // I don't understand what this line of code is doing...
    addToSum(num, i, anArray);
  }
  return undefined
}



myForEach(nums, addToSum);

console.log(sum);
```