# How does this code pass an argument to a callback that takes no arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm sifting through some code and I don't get how this piece of code is able to pass arguments to a callback that takes no arguments.

We start with this object:

```
const oracleEndpoints = {
  pancake: () => fetchPancake(),
  lps: () => fetchLP(endpoints.lps), <-- endpoints.lps is an API url
};
```

And this map:

```
const oracleToIds = new Map()
oracleToIds.set("lps", ["png-snob-avax", "png-png-avax"])
oracleToIds.set("pancake", ["WBNB", "BREW"])
```

Now this is the part I don't get:

```
const promises = oracleToIds.keys().map(key => oracleEndpoints[key](oracleToIds.get(key)));
```

`oracleEndpoints[key]` is an anonymous callback (`() => fetchPancake()` or `() => fetchLP(endpoints.lps)`) and `oracleToIds.get(key)` is an array of strings.

What's going on in this expression `oracleEndpoints[key](oracleToIds.get(key))` then where an unparametised callback is passed an array?

How is it able to do this?

Comment: Could you give more detail as to what the code does, and how you know that the argument - `oracleToIds.get(key)` - is being used? From glancing at the code I agree with you, this should do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check if the array argument is actually being used by anything meaningful. It could easily be a mistake in the code caused by confusion of the writer, given the high level of nesting mashed into a single line of the `const promises` code that you showed.

This would silently cause an error that would only manifest in application usage -- no exception is thrown in JavaScript if you are [passing extra params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694031/what-happens-if-i-call-a-js-method-with-more-parameters-than-it-is-defined-to-ac) to a function.