# How can this function work with a missing parameter

Tags: javascript

How can callback function work with one parameter when it requires 2 (selector and data) to go? Why doesn't it throw an error?

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        links.forEach(function(link){
            link.addEventListener("click",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                ajax("get",e.target.href,render)
            })
        })
        function ajax(url,metodo,callback){
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
            xhr.open(metodo,url)
            xhr.addEventListener("load",function(){
                if(xhr.status==200){
                    callback(xhr.response)
                }
            })
            xhr.send()
        }
        function render(selector,data){
            document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = data
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't *require* a `data` parameter - if it's empty, the `innerHTML` will just become `undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come I can call a function with the wrong number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323881/how-come-i-can-call-a-function-with-an-argument-when-the-function-is-defined-wi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, it is not necessary to call with same number of parameters as defined in function definition. If we do not define a default parameter value in function definition, then parameter becomes type of undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

> Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized
>   with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, there are two new kinds of parameters:
>   default parameters and rest parameters.
>
> **Default parameters:** In JavaScript, parameters of functions default to
>   undefined. However, in some situations it might be useful to set a
>   different default value. This is where default parameters can help.
>
> In the past, the general strategy for setting defaults was to test
>   parameter values in the body of the function and assign a value if
>   they are undefined. If in the following example, no value is provided
>   for b in the call, its value would be undefined  when evaluating a*b
>   and the call to multiply would have returned NaN. However, this is
>   caught with the second line in this example:

```
function multiply(a, b) {
  b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ?  b : 1;

  return a * b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

> With default parameters, the check in the function body is no longer necessary. Now, you can simply put 1 as the default
>   value for b in the function head:

```
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a * b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

For more details, see default parameters in the reference.

> **Rest parameters:** The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an
>   indefinite number of arguments as an array. In the example, we use the
>   rest parameters to collect arguments from the second one to the end.
>   We then multiply them by the first one.

```
 function multiply(multiplier, ...theArgs) {
  return theArgs.map(x => multiplier * x);
}

var arr = multiply(2, 1, 2, 3);
console.log(arr); // [2, 4, 6]
```

**Argument Object:**

> Using the arguments object, you can call a function with more
>   arguments than it is formally declared to accept. This is often useful
>   if you don't know in advance how many arguments will be passed to the
>   function. You can use arguments.length to determine the number of
>   arguments actually passed to the function, and then access each
>   argument using the arguments object.
>
> For example, consider a function that concatenates several strings.
>   The only formal argument for the function is a string that specifies
>   the characters that separate the items to concatenate. The function is
>   defined as follows:

```
 function myConcat(separator) {
   var result = ''; // initialize list
   var i;
   // iterate through arguments
   for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      result += arguments[i] + separator;
   }
   return result;
}
```

> You can pass any number of arguments to this function, and it
>   concatenates each argument into a string "list":

```
// returns "red, orange, blue, "
myConcat(', ', 'red', 'orange', 'blue');

// returns "elephant; giraffe; lion; cheetah; "
myConcat('; ', 'elephant', 'giraffe', 'lion', 'cheetah');

// returns "sage. basil. oregano. pepper. parsley. "
myConcat('. ', 'sage', 'basil', 'oregano', 'pepper', 'parsley');
```

To make it throw error, if same number of argument is not passed in function, [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org) can be used.